# Jolt remove all null values

Tags: specifications, operation, jolt

I want to achieve the JSON transformation using the Jolt processor. I have fields with null in my JSON and I would like to remove all these fields...

```json
{
  "myValue": 345,
  "colorValue": null,
  "degreeDayValue": null,
  "depthValue": null,
  "distanceValue": null
}
```

...to just keep the `myValue` field.

Can I realize this with a Jolt operation removed?

Answer (score 9):

To remove `null` values from the internal array use the below spec at the end of your code:

```json
{
  "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
  "spec": {
    "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is better to use code formattings and give more detail on the answers. Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Answer (score 5):

It is possible, just not straightforward. Requires two steps.

**Spec::**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      // for all keys that have a null value
      //  replace that null value with a placeholder
      "*": "PANTS"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      // match all keys
      "*": {
        // if the value of say "colorValue" is PANTS
        //  then, match but do nothing.
        "PANTS": null,
        // otherwise, any other values are ok
        "*": {
          // "recreate" the key and the non-PANTS value
          // Write the value from 2 levels up the tree the "@1"
          //  to the key from 3 levels up the tree => "&2".
          "@1": "&2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Produces:**

```json
{
  "myValue": 345
}
```

Comment: thx  Milo, it works ! but  sorry my data is little more complex

Comment: complete json payload here in the gist:https://gist.github.com/pgibert/a5804c48d27d9b2f59879946f728e484